# Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By)" because "this.driver" is null helpme please

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I have the following code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAMBX.png)

and this class:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/God0E.png)

when executing it sends me Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By)" because "this.driver" is null

Comment: obviously there is no place where you initialize your driver.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the comment from your code.

Remove the `/*` and `*/` at the beginning and end of the the code.